# How to return to the View the items checked by the CheckBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am developing a project in ASP.net MVC. In my registration form, I have a checkbox where I select the items you would like to add to the database. My form of editing, I have to get these checked items and show the view: all items that are in the grid and the fields that were selected are saved in the database. I would like to return to the View all checked items that are saved in the database.

The code looks like this:

```
   @using Forte.Rastreador.ViewModels
   @using GridMvc.Html

   @model SuperModulosPerfilUsuarioViewModel

 <fieldset>
@Html.Label("Nome do Perfil: ")
@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Descricao)
<br /><br />
 </fieldset>

 <fieldset> //minha checkBOX
<legend>Modulos do Sistema</legend>

@Html.Grid(Model.ModulosSistemas).Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add()
        .Encoded(false)
        .Sanitized(false)
        .SetWidth(30)
        .RenderValueAs(o => Html.CheckBox("Checked", @Model.Check, new { value = o.CodModulo }));

    columns.Add(u => u.DesModulo)
      .Titled("Modulos Perfil")
      .Encoded(false);
})
```

```
               //Action metodo get Editar, onde retorna todo o conteudo de                  visualizacao para a view.
        public ActionResult EditarPerfilUsuario(int CodPerfil)
  {

    var perfilUsuario = PerfilUsuarioRepositorio.ObterPerfilUsuarioPorCodigo(CodPerfil);
    var perfilUsuarioVM = new SuperModulosPerfilUsuarioViewModel();
    perfilUsuarioVM.Descricao = perfilUsuario.Descricao;
    perfilUsuarioVM.ModulosSistemas = ModulosSistemaRepositorio.ListarModulosSistemas();
    perfilUsuarioVM.ModulosDoPerfil = ModulosPerfilRepositorio.ListarModulosDoPerfisPorCodPerfil(CodPerfil);

    foreach (var ms in perfilUsuarioVM.ModulosSistemas)
    {                
        foreach (var mp in perfilUsuarioVM.ModulosDoPerfil)
        {
            if (ms.CodModulo == mp.CodModulo)
            {
                perfilUsuarioVM.Check = true;
            }
        }                
     }

    return View("EditarPerfilUsuario", perfilUsuarioVM);
}

public IEnumerable<ModulosSistema> ListarModulosSistemas()    //metodos listar que se encontram no meu repositorio
{
    return this.Context.ModulosSistemas;
}

public IEnumerable<ModulosDoPerfil> ListarModulosDoPerfisPorCodPerfil(int CodPerfil)
{
    return this.Context.ModulosDoPerfil.Where(c=>c.CodPerfil==CodPerfil);
}
```

Comment: In your controller pass a model to the view that has the status of the checkboxes

Comment: Need to get all the elements! and the elements of the same id that were saved in the bank, are true, and they are not false! I can only get the values that were saved in the bank! I can not get all, and true mark only those who were saved in the bank!

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to pass data from your view to your controller?